# css dropdown menu at wrong position

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the positioning of a pure css dropdown menu. You can find the website at:
[link to website](http://knowledgeispower.kn.funpic.de/)

When you hover of "Tutorials" (im not really doing any but it is for learning) and "Blog", you see that the dropdown menu position is not directly under the tab, it is moved to the right.

How can I place the dropdown menu under the tab? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to edit the file "main.css", change this:

```
ul#nav li ul{
position:absolute;
display:none;
}
```

For this:

```
ul#nav li ul{
position:absolute;
display:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

I think it will solve your position problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the browser defaults for `margin`'s, `padding`'s etc. on elements.

The minimum you could do at the top of your CSS is:

`html,body,ul,li,p { margin:0;padding:0 }`

Look up http://cssreset.com for more options.

Comment: Resets are not recommended. Browser defaults are fairly consistent, and should be overridden on a case-by-case basis as needed, as opposed to the "shotgun" approach that most resets take. This is referred to as "normalization".

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your browser automatically adds custom CSS to some elements, like "ul" tags in this case.
I'm using Chrome and I see this style for all the sub-lists: -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
So just add this css:

```
ul#nav li ul{
padding-left:0;
}
```

Comment: those styles are chrome's inspector's own user agent styles

Comment: Yes. Yes they are. And their defined as defaults by the browser. They can be overridden by styles like the above code. There is no reason for this downvote.